# Recognizing whitespace in file path in python

Tags: python, python-3.9

I'm trying to open a file from python (jupyter notebook) but it doesn't recognize whitespace in the path:

```
import os
import win32com.client

# Open a specified word document
wordapp = win32com.client.Dispatch('Word.Application')

# Change this depending on your file location
document = wordapp.Documents.Open('C:/Users/sam/Documents/New folder/testfile.docx')

# Gimme the links
wordapp.ActiveDocument

brokenlinks = {}
counter = wordapp.ActiveDocument.Lists(1).ListParagraphs.Count

for para in (wordapp.ActiveDocument.Lists(1).ListParagraphs):
    
    for link in (para.Range.Hyperlinks):
        try:
            link.Follow()
        except:
            if counter in brokenlinks:
                brokenlinks[counter] = brokenlinks[counter] + ", " + link.TextToDisplay
            else:
                brokenlinks[counter] = link.TextToDisplay
    counter -= 1

# Number of broken links in the document    
print('Number of footnotes with broken links:' + ' ' + str(len(brokenlinks.values())),'\n')

# Print broken links in each footnote
for i, (counter, value) in enumerate(brokenlinks.items()):
    print(str(counter) + '. ' + value + '\n')
```

Output:

```
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Word', "Sorry, we couldn't find your file. Was it moved, renamed, or deleted?\r (C:\\//Users/sam/Documents/New%20f...)", 'wdmain11.chm', 24654, -2146823114), None)
```

The code works when I rename the folder to "New_folder". So the issue is the whitespace in the path. Is there a way to recognize it? It should also work if my target file has whitespaces too, for example, `'C:/Users/sam/Documents/New folder/test file.docx'` .

Comment: Why do you say that it's the whitespace in the path that is the problem?

Comment: @Andy, because when I rename my folder to ``` New_folder```, it works.

Comment: Does "it doesn't work" mean unexpected behavior or an error?

Comment: @blackbrandt the output is the same as above.

Comment: Given the path `C:/Users/sam/Documents/New folder`, `C:/Users/sam/Documents` is the directory name, and `New folder` is the filename.  `os.path.dirname()` is doing exactly what it's designed to do, which is apparently not what you want to be done here.

Answer (score 0):

try this (if you are **NOT using the shell**):

```
path= r"C:\Users\sam\Documents\New folder"
directory = os.path.dirname(path)
```

Comment: No change. It's the same output.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that you have forward slashes in your directory, I believe that you just need to add one more forward slash onto your directory path as in the following code snippet.

```
import os

directory = os.path.dirname('/home/craig/Python_Programs/PathName/My Documents/')
print(directory)
```

Here was my test output in the terminal.

```
@Una:~/Python_Programs/PathName$ python3 PathName.py 
/home/craig/Python_Programs/PathName/My Documents
```

Give that a try.

Comment: yes that worked. However, please see my edited post for the real problem.

Comment: Oh.  I also see that it is Windows and I was on a Linux system.  However, you might try adding a slash after the file name as well.  When I changed the variable "directory" to "/home/craig/Python_Programs/PathName/My Documents/Test Data.txt/" and opened the file using that variable, it did work.

Comment: I tried `"C:/Users/sam/Documents/New folder/testfile.docx/"` and `'"C:/Users/sagarwal/Documents/New folder/testfile.docx/"'` but both throw the same error as before.

Comment: Okay.  Might be different in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using `pathlib` and following changes to the code -

```
import pathlib
path = pathlib.Path(r'C:/Users/sam/Documents/New folder/testfile.docx')
document = wordapp.Documents.Open(str(path))
```

This also works if my file name is say `test file.docx`.